# Uninstall previous version APK and remove all data on update

Tags: java, android, apk

I could really use a hand with the situation that Im having.
I inherited an app, and I am facing difficulties when it comes to
deployment.
When the users download the app from play store, I would like to have their previous version app
uninstalled first, with all the data removed.
Then they would get to update/install the new version.

In my search for the answers I found this bit:
gradle:aware Make ...
Would that be a way to go, and if so how would I go about it?
Gradle:aware Make seem to work when I test debug, can it somehow be embeded in the app's apk?

Hope Im making sense.
Thanks.

Comment: `uninstalled first` it is uninstalled during update in face, but without clearing user data. You can delete user data manually by cleanin your app inner directory

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So if I understood correctly, it would be enough to detect update in code, and clear all app data and cache?

Comment: yes, I can offer such an algorithm: On application stary you check the app's `versionCode` and get the last saved `versionCode` from shared preferences. If current `versionCode` is higher, then it is a new version. You need to clear data and store the nev version into shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this via the apk. gradle is only for your local machine. You need to write code that wipes out all the user data yourself. i would use a shared prefs boolean to keep track and if it is not set run some code that deletes all the users local data